# Insert number into sorted list using List.fold_right

Tags: ocaml, fold

I am trying to insert a number `x` into a sorted list `l` using Ocaml's `List.fold_right` and return the list with the inserted element. I have figured out a way to insert it if the element is to go at the front of the list or in the middle of the list, however I cannot figure out how to code the case where the element is larger than every element in the list and thus must go at the end.

Here is what I have so far:

```
let insert_number (x: int) (l: int list): int list =
  List.fold_right l ~f:(
    fun cur -> fun acc -> 
      if x < cur then cur::x::accum 
      else cur::accum
  ) ~init: []
```

Using this with a test case like:

```
insert_number (3) ([1; 2; 4]);;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

gives the correct answer. However, with a test case like this:

```
insert_number (3) ([1; 2]);;
- : int list = [1; 2]
```

the number is not inserted because it should be added to the end of the list.

Could someone help me understand how I am supposed to integrate this case into the function used with `List.fold_right`.

Comment: You have to use `fold_right`? One idea I can think of is to always append the element, but then pop it back off again if the next element is smaller. I can't see how doing this with a fold wouldn't be awkward no matter what though.

Comment: Make things a little easier on yourself and condense `fun cur -> fun acc -> ` to `fun cur acc -> `.

Comment: I don't necessarily have to use `fold_right`. I mentioned it because that was the `List` module function that got me closest to my desired result. Is there a better function in the `List` module that's better suited to this problem?

Comment: `List.fold_left` is tail-recursive, so will work better for inserting into larger lists.

Comment: Both `fold_left` and `fold_right` are O(n) for the length of the list. Writing your own insert function can short-circuit once insertion has taken place, which need only be _worst case_ O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fold works by passing along a set of state as it iterates over each element in a list (or other foldable data structure). The function passed in takes both the current element and that state.

I think you're really really close, but you need as Jeffrey suggests a boolean flag to indicate whether or not the value has been inserted. This will prevent multiple insertions and if the flag is still false when the fold is done, we can detect that and add the value to insert.

This `match` also serves the purpose of giving us an opportunity to discard the no longer needed boolean flag.

```
let insert v lst =
  match List.fold_right 
    (fun x (inserted, acc) -> 
       if v > x && not inserted then (true, x::v::acc) 
       else (inserted, x::acc))
    lst
    (false, []) with
  | (true, lst) -> lst
  | (_,    lst) -> v::lst
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you so much! I did not realize that I could initialize the boolean flag in a tuple for `List.fold_right`. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at `List.fold_right` is that it looks at each element of the list in turn, but in reverse order. For each element it transforms the current accumulated result to a new one.

Thinking backward from the end of the list, what you want to do, in essence, is look for the first element of the list that's less than `x`, then insert x at that point.

So the core of the code might look something like this:

```
if element < x then element :: x :: accum else element :: accum
```

However, all the earlier elements of the list will also be less than `x`. So (it seems to me) you need to keep track of whether you've inserted `x` into the list or not. This makes the accumulated state a little more complicated.

I coded this up and it works for me after fixing up the case where `x` goes at the front of the list.

Perhaps there is a simpler way to get it to work, but I couldn't come up with one.

Answer (score 0):

As I alluded to in a comment, it's possible to avoid the extra state and post-processing by always inserting the element and effectively doing a "local sort" of the last two elements:

```
let insert_number x l =
  List.fold_right (
    fun cur -> function
      | [] when x > cur -> [cur; x]
      | [] -> [x; cur]
      | x::rest when x > cur -> cur::x::rest
      | x::rest -> x::cur::rest 
  ) l []
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, since folding doesn't seem to actually be a requirement, here's a version using simple recursion instead, which I think is far more comprehensible:

```
let rec insert_number x = function 
  | [] -> [x]
  | cur::rest when cur > x -> x::cur::rest
  | cur::rest -> cur::insert_number x rest
```